# how to reduced loading time in jsp to struts2.0

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am using maven project and using Application server(jboss 7.1.2) 
if login on screen the loading time is very high,so i need my application loading time is reduced,can u please explain me how to reduced the loading time on my screen.

Comment: Please be more precise. Have you debugged the code? Where does your code need the most time? Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as starting point.

Comment: maybe try this? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Performance+Tuning

Answer (score 0):

1) don't include .js and .css file having link like bellow.

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
```

copy such file into local and try to include.

2) The file (.css or .js) which is required include only that file.

3) most important point.

Open **firebug** or **Inspect Element** then goto **Net** option there you can check which file is taking how long time to load.

Thanks I think this may help you.

Comment: loading time is 6.23 s

Comment: I don't know what type of data you are loading and your question is not clear. I told just the common thing where page get slow down.